# Finding the minima of a multivariable function

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $3a^4-4ba^3+b^4 \ge 0$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$.

To prove this it is enough to prove that the minimum of this function is $0$. But, how to do it? There is no given constraints to use Lagrange Multiplier method.

Comment: Having no constraints makes it usually easier, not more difficult.  You need to read up on optimising a function in more than one variable.

Comment: I studied the Lagrange Multiplier method only today so have not used it in many problems. I got the answer using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use calculus, some algebra may suffice.

First note that putting $a=b$ makes the LHS zero, so factor that out.
$3a^4-4ba^3+b^4 = (a-b)^2 (3a^2+2ab+b^2)$

Now we need to only show $3a^2+2ab+b^2 = 2a^2 + (a+b)^2\ge 0$, which is evident.

Comment: How is that square on (a-b)?

Comment: When you factor once, you get an expression which has $a-b$ again as a factor.  Try it out.  I assume you know how to use long division to factor.